# drupal creating database queried pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm starting to learn drupal and hopefully this is a easy newbie question for you to answer but my firm basically has a very large data set and I want to present it to the public.

We do research on firms and have a database with a company name and all the data we have about the firm(its mainly numbers/estimates).  So is there a way to create a view that does this for us?

Creating individual pages is not very practical since we have several thousand companies we have studied over the years.

If there isn't anything easy, then is it possible to create a php page that takes the company name from the url and then queries the database and presents all the data to users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [views](http://views.doc.logrus.com/) module.  It can take a bit of work to customize it for a specific database, but is very flexible once you do.

Comment: I'll check it out, Thanks Karl. Just to confirm I can create a standard view for all companies for example, and then users will be able to type "ibm" or "goog" and get the respective data for that entry?

Comment: @Lostsoul, it lets you define arguments as part of the url, so you can type something like `mysite.com/report/ibm` and it will use the `ibm` part in your query.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted.  Thank you so much.  One last question(hopefully not outside the scope of this question), but can I use views within views? So if I have multiple datebases that reference can I use views to query both of them and provide them on the same page?

Comment: @Lostsoul, you can do that by defining relationships, which are basically joins.

Comment: amazing..thank you, I was just reading up on views and its exactly what I wanted.  You saved me from writing a massive amount of queries.  Thank you so much Karl!